# Trigger smooth scroll in html appended within D3 script

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, smooth-scrolling

I have smooth scrolling in my HTML, which works fine. But I have a D3 script where I append a few html elements with hrefs at the end of an animation. But when you click on those links, the smooth scroll doesn't fire, because the D3 script doesn't know about the JQuery. Any ideas about how to merge?

```
  g.selectAll('circle')
      .transition()
        .duration(circle_delay)
        .style('opacity', '0');
  d3.selectAll("#header h2")
      .transition()
        .duration(circle_delay)
        .style('opacity', '0')
        .remove()
  d3.selectAll('#imagediv div')
    .transition()
      .delay(circle_delay)
      .remove()

  setTimeout(function() {
    d3.select('#imagediv')
      .append('h1')
        .style('opacity', '0')
        .html('<a href="#text_div">Read stuff</a>')
      .transition()
        .duration(fade_time)
        .style('opacity', '1')

    d3.select('#imagediv')
      .append('h1')
        .style('opacity', '0')
        .html('or')
      .transition()
        .delay(fade_time)
      .transition()
        .duration(fade_time)
        .style('opacity', '1')

    d3.select('#imagediv')
      .append('h1')
        .style('opacity', '0')
        .html('<a href="#data_div">Play with data stuff</a>')
      .transition()
        .delay(fade_time)
      .transition()
        .duration(fade_time)
        .style('opacity', '1')
  }, circle_delay)
```

Comment: Did you add the *jQuery* script and all needed library? Is your script loading inside the *jQuery* function on document ready?

Comment: It will be easier for the community to help you by attaching code snippet.